# Which package provides bluez-test-audio script on (K)ubuntu 16.04 LTS?

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, sound, kubuntu, bluetooth

After the recent LTS upgrade from Kubuntu 14.04 to 16.04 I noticed that the package `bluez` no longer contains the Python script `bluez-test-audio`.

Why?

It has been very useful to me for connecting and disconnection specific Bluetooth devices from script / command line.

Is there any alternative to this?

Comment: P.S. I tried copying the script `/usr/bin/bluez-test-audio` from my old machine, but it produces errors.